# How can I squeeze grain out of chickens more efficiently?

Tags: glitch-2011

I know I have to squeeze a chicken, but having to find 5 chickens to make a single unit a flour, it seems like I'm missing something.

Comment: Is is just me or is squeezing grain out of chickens really creepy?

Comment: @Matt Seems perfectly natural to me. Why wouldn't you squeeze a chicken for grain?

Comment: @MatthewRead Not as creepy as eggs growing on trees

Comment: What about searching in pig droppings for packets of seeds to plant? Actually... that's basically what happens in real life.

Comment: @fredley Still not as creepy as watering a wood tree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invest some time learning [Animal Kinship](http://www.glitch.com/skills/23/). The higher levels of this skill allow you to squeeze more grain from chickens, not to mention squeezing the same chicken multiple times.  [Animal Kinship 6](http://www.glitch.com/skills/28/) and [7](http://www.glitch.com/skills/29/) also raise the chance that you'll get bonus goodies and super harvests to a level where you see them regularly.

Comment: Also, walk up to a chicken and spam the 'enter' key. When you can squeeze them 4 times a day for 5 grain per squeeze (Animal Kinship V), the result is very quick grain accrual.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the two Fecundity powders to force all animals on a level to 'drop' a whole bunch of their product all at once - meat, eggs, butterfly milk. If you do it near chickens you will get like 4-6 units of grain per chicken, which you can just pick up without using any energy. Be careful though, because any other player nearby is free to pick up any of the bounty as well, so it's best to do it when you're on a level by yourself and there are lots of animals around.